# Proof regarding the number of elements in a group, which are not self-inverse

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, proof-verification

I have to prove that the number of elements $x$ in a group with $x\neq x^{-1}$ is always even.

My thoughts:

That means the number of elements $x$, which are not self-inverse, is even. By definition of a group, each element has one distinct inverse element. We don't count the identity element, since it is self-inverse. Let's say the number of elements (without the identity element) is odd. That would mean there does exist one element $y$, with $y=y^{-1}$. That would mean, that $y$ is self inverse, which is a contradiction. Therefore the number must be even.

Is my proof correct?

Comment: Simply note that the elements you want to count come in pairs $\{g,g^{-1}\}$. Thus their total is twice the number of such pairs, an even number.

Comment: The step where you write "That would mean ..." really lacks a justification.

Comment: @HenningMakholm: Why? The only way a group could have an odd number of elements is when at least one element is self-inverse.

Comment: @de_dust: Yes, that is _what you're being asked to prove_. Simply asserting that it is true does not constitute a proof.

Comment: As a consequence, every group of even order has a least one element of order two.

Comment: @ÉricGuirbal: Could you explain why this is a consequence?

Comment: @de_dust: Suppose $G$ is a group of even order. As the cardinal of the set $\{x\in G \mid x^{-1} \neq x\}$ is even, the cardinal of its complement $\{x\in G \mid x^2 = e\}$ is even too.  As this latter set is not empty (it contains the identity element), the group $G$ has at least one $x\neq e$ such that $x^2 = e$.

Answer (score 1):

> This answer is just a synopsis of the answers given in comments, so the question doesn't hang around forever looking unanswered.

As per comments, the supplied proof has problems: it assumes what it's trying to prove.

To prove the result, note that the non-self-inverse elements come in pairs: if $x$ is not self-inverse then $x\ne x^{-1}$, i.e. $x^{-1}$ is also not self-inverse. If the group is finite, the number of non-self-inverse elements is even, as required.

This result has an interesting corollary.

**Corollary.** If a group $G$ has even order then $G$ has at least one element of order 2.

*Proof.* The number of elements in $G$ is even, and (as just shown) the number of non-self-inverse elements in $G$ is even, so the number of self-inverse elements in $G$ is even.  Since the identity $e$ is self-inverse, there must be at least one other self-inverse element of $G$ to make the total even.